# Python: Creating a list of dicts, where keys don't have quotes?

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I'm using the visjs plugin to create a timeline on my page. The timeline code requires me to give it multiple dicts in a list which look like this:

```
  var items = new vis.DataSet([
     {id: 1, content: 'item 1', start: '2013-04-20'},
     {id: 2, content: 'item 2', start: '2013-04-14'},
     {id: 3, content: 'item 3', start: '2013-04-16', end: '2013-04-19'},
  ]);
```

Now I'm trying to create something like this for my Index View by using a for loop and adding my dicts to a list, which I then put in my context and use it in my template. My code looks like this:

```
class ItemIndex(SingleTableMixin, FilterView):
    model = Item
    context_object_name = 'items'
    template_name = 'accounting/item/item_index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        items = Item.objects.all()
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        dict_list = []

        for item in items:
            dict = {
                "id": item.pk,
                "content": Item (# {item.pk})',
                "start": str(item.start), #DateField
                "end": str(item.end), #DateField
            }
            dict_list.append(dict)
        context.update({
            "dict_list": dict_list,
        })
        return context
```

Now I don't find this is the prettiest solution, but I don't know anything better (maybe someone has a better idea).

In my html I'm calling the `dict_list` like this:

```
var items = new vis.DataSet(
                "{{dict_list}}"
            );
```

My problem is that the list I'm getting back looks like this:

```
[{'id': 3, 'content': 'Item (# 3)', 'start': '2020-01-01', 'end': '2020-01-03'}, {'id': 4, 'content': 'Item (# 4)', 'start': '2020-01-01', 'end': 'None'}]
```

My problem is that the quotes around the keys "destroy" the whole list and thus my timeline isn't shown properly.

Is there a good solution to somehow create the dicts without the quotes around the keys?

I'm using Python 3 and Django 2.2.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You should use Json to convert the Python data to JavaScript.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I tried so by doing `json.dumps(dict_list)` problem is: it stays the same and worse: if I try to use Umlauts for my `content` value (like "Ermäßigung") I receive something like `Erm\u00e4\u00dfigung (# 3)`

Comment: you need to mark it as safe when rendering, and then parse it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You here have a Python object, and by using `{{ dict_list }}` you get a *HTML escaped* version of the `str(..)` of that object. You probably better use JSON as an intermediate format. You thus first JSON-encode the object in the context:

```
context.update(
    dict_list=json.dumps(dict_list),
)
```

At the template side, you can then parse the JSON back. You should mark the `dict_list` variable as safe, to ensure that it does not HTML-escape it:

```
var items = new vis.DataSet(
    JSON.parse('{{ dict_list|safe }}')
);
```